# Javascript on Firefox gives 'Invalid Date'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, timezone, frontend

Instead of asking users about their preferred time zone I made server to provide time in UTC and a small Javascript which converts it to local time on browser end. The following fragment works in Chrome but not in Firefox. Why?

Is there a universal way to convert UTC time to local time in any reasonable browser?

```
var timestamp_utc="2016-06-16 15:43:40.086670";
                    n = timestamp_utc.indexOf('.');
                    document.write((new Date(Date.parse(timestamp_utc.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : s.length)+" UTC"))).toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, put it in [the specification's date/time format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format). In your case, you can do that by changing the space to a `T` and adding a `Z` to the end:

```
var dt = new Date(timestamp_utc.replace(" ", "T") + "Z");
```

No need to remove the fractional portion unless you want to. If you want to, and you know for sure it's there, then:

```
var dt = new Date(timestamp_utc.split(".")[0].replace(" ", "T") + "Z");
```

Examples:

```js
var timestamp_utc = "2016-06-16 15:43:40.086670";
console.log(new Date(timestamp_utc.replace(" ", "T") + "Z"));
console.log(new Date(timestamp_utc.split(".")[0].replace(" ", "T") + "Z"));
```

---

Note: `Date.parse(String)` and `new Date(String)` use the same parsing algorithm, so there's never any need to do `new Date(Date.parse(x))`.

Comment: Many thanks. BTW is there a simple library to output something like "2 minutes ago" for most recent dates?

Comment: @Castle: I seem to recall one called "timeago" or similar. Somewhere on either MSO or MSE I believe they say what lib they use for it here.

Comment: @Castle - Look into [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).  It can handle all of your parsing and formatting needs, including "2 minutes ago".

Comment: @MattJohnson: Wow, how did I miss that Moment [does human duration formatting](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/)?!

Comment: Yep.  There are a few different functions for that.  The most commonly used is [`.fromNow()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)